# React Native + Jest + Enzyme: Why does Enzyme not recognize some components?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently learning unit testing with Enzyme.

There seems to be a weird behavior: Enzyme seemingly randomly does not recognize certain components. Let me give you the examples:

Here is my `SafeContainer` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";

import styles from "./styles";

const SafeContainer = ({ children }) => {
  return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>{children}</SafeAreaView>;
};

SafeContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any
};

export default SafeContainer;
```

And here is my `AuthInput` component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import colors from "../../config/constants/themes";
import styles from "./styles";

class AuthInput extends PureComponent {
  handleChange = value => {
    const { onChange, name } = this.props;
    onChange(name, value);
  };

  handleTouch = () => {
    const { onTouch, name } = this.props;
    onTouch(name);
  };

  render() {
    const { placeholder, error } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={[styles.input, error ? styles.errorInput : null]}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor={colors.$lightGrey}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onBlur={this.handleTouch}
          {...this.props}
        />
        {error && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AuthInput.propTypes = {
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  error: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onTouch: PropTypes.func
};

export default AuthInput;
```

Now here is how I test that the `SafeContainer` uses the SafeAreaView:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import SafeContainer from "./SafeContainer";

describe("SafeContainer", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<SafeContainer />);
    });

    it("should render a <SafeAreaView />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find("SafeAreaView")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

I tried do use the same thing to test that the `AuthInput` wraps it's inner component inside a `<View />`:

```
describe("AuthInput", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<AuthInput />);
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find("View")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

But somehow this test fails. If I use the same structure to test for the `<TextInput ... />` it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in how the different items you're testing are imported.  TextInput works because it is a Named Reference.  In Enzyme you test Named References with a string like this: `wrapper.find("myComponent")`.

Whereas the components you are trying to test are Direct References so you you would test them in Enzyme without the quotes, like this: `wrapper.find(myComponent)`.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thank you very much for your answer :)